# Step detection using Google Activity Recognition Api

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am to develop a step counter application, Which is to support android 4.3 (Api Level 18) onwards.
Firstly, I saw the accelerometer way But making own consequences is a very much time taking process.
Secondly, I saw the google "Activity Recognition Api", Which gives what activity the user is performing But It only gives the type of activity, doesn't count the steps during walking/running/bicycling And not performing well.

Some folks say to use the api introduced in KitKat version But My app supports Api 18 onwards.

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

At this time Activity Recognition does not count steps. It merely indicates that the user is doing some known activity.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UserInput